# Animacion anda con Class pero no con Id

Tags: javascript, html, css

La pregunta es: Por que [ESTE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPLyyz) ejemplo anda asi como esta, pero si el JS lo cambio por el siguente, deja de andar:

```
var clicked = 0;
$(".ripple").click(function() {
 var clicked = 1;
 document.getElementById("di").addClass("expanded");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) pertenece a `JQuery`, con lo que necesitas seleccionar el elemento con la función `JQuery` para que el método te funcione;

```js
var clicked = 0;
$(".ripple").click(function() {
 var clicked = 1;
 $('#di').addClass("expanded");
});
```

Si lo que quieres es utilizar JavaScript plano, tienes el elemento `className`o como te han dicho en la otra respuesta, `setAttribute()`. Una forma sería;

```js
var clicked = 0;
$(".ripple").click(function() {
 var clicked = 1;
 document.getElementById("di").className += " expanded";
});
```

Si quieres ver más puedes consultar [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Answer (score 1):

No te funciona por que estas juntando JavaScript nativo con jQuery, si lo quieres con JavaScript nativo debe ser así:

```js
var clicked = 0;
$(".ripple").click(function() {
 var clicked = 1;
 document.getElementById("di").setAttribute("class", "expanded");
});
```

```css
#di {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 700ms ease-out;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

}
#di.expanded {
  transform: scale(20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="di" class="ripple">
asds
</div>
```

Esa es la solución a tu inquietud, pero reitero no debes mezclar jQuery con JavaScript nativo de esa forma.